# (Xcode 14.2) Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, android-studio

**Flutter Doctor :**

MACBOOKs-MacBook-Pro:Parcelstar-Merchant-Flutter macbook$ flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.9, on macOS 12.6 21G115 darwin-x64, locale en-US)
• Flutter version 3.3.9 on channel stable at /Users/macbook/Development/flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision b8f7f1f986 (5 months ago), 2022-11-23 06:43:51 +0900
• Engine revision 8f2221fbef
• Dart version 2.18.5
• DevTools version 2.15.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)
• Android SDK at /Users/macbook/Library/Android/sdk
• Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.1
• Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.2)
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• Build 14C18
• CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2022.3.1)
• IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
• iPhone 5s (mobile) • cfd946de749b8b2937909b5f5d586aeee720bc28 • ios            • iOS 12.5.7 16H81
• macOS (desktop)    • macos                                    • darwin-x64     • macOS 12.6 21G115 darwin-x64
• Chrome (web)       • chrome                                   • web-javascript • Google Chrome 112.0.5615.137

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
• All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
MACBOOKs-MacBook-Pro:Parcelstar-Merchant-Flutter macbook$

**Android Studio Consol**

Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 5s in debug mode...
Updating minimum iOS deployment target to 11.0.
Upgrading Podfile
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: 548DQPU297
Running pod install...
CocoaPods' output:
↳
Preparing

```
Analyzing dependencies

Inspecting targets to integrate
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)

Fetching external sources
-> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Flutter`
-> Fetching podspec for `connectivity` from `.symlinks/plugins/connectivity/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `connectivity_plus` from `.symlinks/plugins/connectivity_plus/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `flutter_facebook_auth` from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_facebook_auth/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `flutter_secure_storage` from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_secure_storage/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `image_picker_ios` from `.symlinks/plugins/image_picker_ios/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `package_info_plus` from `.symlinks/plugins/package_info_plus/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `path_provider_foundation` from `.symlinks/plugins/path_provider_foundation/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `permission_handler_apple` from `.symlinks/plugins/permission_handler_apple/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `shared_preferences_foundation` from `.symlinks/plugins/shared_preferences_foundation/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `sqflite` from `.symlinks/plugins/sqflite/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `url_launcher_ios` from `.symlinks/plugins/url_launcher_ios/ios`

Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
  CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_c_7_9.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/c/7/9/Reachability/3.2/Reachability.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_d_d_6.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/d/d/6/ReachabilitySwift/5.0.0/ReachabilitySwift.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_b_3_c.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/b/3/c/FBSDKLoginKit/15.1.0/FBSDKLoginKit.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_4_2_c.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/4/2/c/FlutterMacOS/3.0.0/FlutterMacOS.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_f_4_e.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/f/4/e/FMDB/2.7.5/FMDB.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/f/4/e/FMDB/2.7.5/FMDB.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/f/4/e/FMDB/2.7.5/FMDB.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/b/3/c/FBSDKLoginKit/15.1.0/FBSDKLoginKit.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FBSDKLoginKit":
  In Podfile:
    flutter_facebook_auth (from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_facebook_auth/ios`) was resolved to 5.0.4, which depends on
      FBSDKLoginKit (~> 15.1.0)

Specs satisfying the `FBSDKLoginKit (~> 15.1.0)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:317:in `raise_error_unless_state'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:299:in `block in unwind_for_conflict'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:297:in `tap'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:297:in `unwind_for_conflict'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:682:in `attempt_to_activate'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:254:in `process_topmost_state'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:182:in `resolve'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:43:in `resolve'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:94:in `resolve'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1078:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1076:in `resolve_dependencies'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:124:in `analyze'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:416:in `analyze'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:241:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:240:in `resolve_dependencies'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:161:in `install!'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

Exception: Error running pod install

I have removed the data from Run Script. but its not working

-> Targets ->go to Build Settings ->Click Run Script -> Remove script data

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, the FBSDKLoginKit requires iOS minimum deployment target 12.0 while yours is 11 so it cannot find the satisfy version, so it stops the build process.

Ref: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/main/FBSDKLoginKit.podspec

> s.ios.deployment_target = '12.0'

Comment: thank you for your answer but still its not working